# positioning text within ItemTemplate - Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I always got problems with elements positioning in windows phone. hope someone can help me:
I've a Listbox dinamically populatem from code behind:

```
<ListBox Name="list" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"  Style="{StaticResource list_service_item}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

the style is defined in App.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="list_service_item" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="25"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Peru" />
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 5"/>
    </Style>
```

and looks like is working correctly except for the alignment property.

if the listbox items have the same length all works well, but if one of them is longer all the others align themselves to the start of the longer item instead of remain centered:

[image]

how can i solve this?

Comment: Are you *sure* that they are aligning to the start of the longer item and not just centred, but coincidentally lining up with the start of the long item? Can you show us an image?

Comment: here's a [screenshot](http://i338.photobucket.com/albums/n430/jack_the_beast/items.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the ItemContainer for each ListBoxItem stretch to the width of the ListBox:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
            Value="Stretch" />
  </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `TextBlock.TextAlignment` property?:

```
<Style x:Key="list_service_item" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="25" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Peru" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" /><!--<<< Used here-->
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 5"/>
</Style>
```

> Disclaimer: This works for WPF, but I can't guarantee that it works for Windows Phone 8

UPDATE >>>

Ok, after seeing your picture I would agree that it is not working as you expect. However, I think that It could be more of a case that the items are not placed correctly. You can try this:

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ... />
```

If that does not work, you could try setting that property to `Stretch` so that the items fill the space and then that could give the `TextBlock`s the to centre themselves:

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ... />
```

Comment: this solution seems to align all the items to the left...i don't know why...however i solved with Doc's answer. thank you very much anyway :)